# Blazor.Client cannot see Blazor.Server on client startup and breakpoints not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor solution, it has a .client project and a .server project.

When I select the client as the startup it cannot read my api's on the .server and when I select the .server as a startup it will not hit breakpoints set in my .client.

I have tried using a multiple startup project setting but it still does not read the server APIs.

this is the launchsettings in the server app, if I have the inspect url in there the app will not start and has this error

[image]

```
 "SeekaPortal.Server": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
}
```

this is the startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {


        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;

        });
        
        services.AddDbContext<SeekaportalContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PortalConnection")));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.ConfigureIdentity();
        services.ConfigureJwt(Configuration);
        services.ConfigureServices();
        services.AddControllers();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
   

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });


    }
```

how can I get either the client to read the server or the breakpoint on the client app to be hit when the server is the startup?

Many Thanks

Comment: You must start the server only if your app is hosted (ASP.NET hosted checkbox when you have created the app). Share the source code where your Client doesn't stop on debug.

Comment: yes it is asp.net hosted

Comment: You have to set the server as the startup project. Its hosts the client and you will be able to debug that as well. If you set the Client as the startup project it will launch but the server will not be started. If you start the server seperately the security will not work.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem I am having is that it is not letting me debug the client.
every breakpoint just says "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unbound breakpoint"

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: @NicolaBiada I have updated the OP with some code

Answer (score 0):

During startup of Client app (webassembly) the debugger shouldn't be ready to attach to the process. In this case during methods like OnInitialized your breakpointa are not reached.

In order to allow breakpoints work you need to add a `Task.Delay` or an `await Task.Delay` for asynchronous methods.

You can use a condition to activate the delay only when you're in debug mode, like:

```cs
#if DEBUG
   Task.Delay(10000);
#endif
```

Take a look to official Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: even this does not work, just says the breakpoint will not be hit and has a warning symbol on it